# how to get which user or group has file/folder access in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I want to know which user or groups has file/folder access(permission) in windows using PowerShell?

I tried it by using this code:

```
$Files = "D:\Akki\data\*.txt"
Get-Acl  $Files | Format-Table -property PSPath, Owner
```

But it shows only owner of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would export the results to a CSV to make it easier to process/read.. try this

```
Get-ChildItem C:\filepath\folder -Recurse | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName} |Export-Csv 'C:\results.csv'
```

Comment: how to display only filename,owner and AccessToString?

Comment: Do you want my PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

Get-ACL returns an object with 3 main properties Path, Owner and Access, this last one has the information you need and you can get it doing this:

```
 (get-acl $folder).Access.IdentityReference | select value
```

That will give you something like this:

```
PS C:\users\rsosa012\Documents\Scripts\Powershell> (get-acl $a[3]).Access.IdentityReference | select value

Value
-----
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
BUILTIN\Administrators
DOM\user2
DOM\user1
```

Data that you can store in a variable and do what you please with it